# jQuery .focus() on textarea not working

Tags: jquery, focus, textarea

I got this code:

```
<textarea id="status" placeholder="Write here..." name="new_entry"></textarea>
```

and this:

```
$('#status').focus(function() {
    alert('focused!');
});
```

I want the alert to start when the textarea is focused on, but it doesn't work...

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/eVvCn/ .. Are you loading up jQuery correctly?

Comment: Were you able to find the solution? I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's the working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/X6HDZ/1/)

HTML

```
<textarea id="status" placeholder="Write here..." name="new_entry"></textarea>
```

JS

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#status').focus(function() {
        alert('focused!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If the text area which your are trying to bind focus to is loaded dynamically [using ajax or something], then you have to bind the live event of focus. Something like this

```
$('#status').live('focus', function() {
alert('focused!');
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#status').focus(function() {
        alert('focused!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery is written correctly. See this similar [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UFvA2/). Check with a debugger (in Chrome or Firebug), is the `focus` method being called? You can try putting the code in a `$('document').ready()` function.

```
<textarea id="status" placeholder="Write here..." name="new_entry"></textarea>
<textarea id="status2" placeholder="Write here..." name="new_entry"></textarea>

$('#status').focus(function() {
    $('#status2').val("wheee");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this instead :

```
$(function(){
    $('#status').click(function() {
        alert('focused!');
    });
});
```

hope it'll help